# Angular login token and get user data synchronously

Tags: angular

My use case seems to be simple, yet despite my efforts its just not quite working correctly.

In my angular application, I have a login component that simply calls a login method on my auth service.

I need this login method to do two things:

1. Make an API call to get my token
2. Then use that token to call my
   user service to get more user data.

Once the results from BOTH calls are complete the the login method can return with a true or false observable to determine success.

My two calls seems to be firing off correctly by nesting the subscribe functions. Yet the login method returns its value before the second call is done, because it fires asynchronously.

So in my UI, I get a momentary "Login failed" before the 2nd call completes then it works as expected.

There must be a better way! **I'm using Angular 6.**

```
private loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

this.retrieveToken(username, password).subscribe(result => {
  this.retrieveUserProfile().subscribe(result =>{
    this.loggedIn$.next(true);
  })
})

return this.isLoggedIn  // this returns before retrieve profile is completed
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Firsy of all, you need to use something like mergeMap rather then subscribe for multiple observables

also any statement outside of the obserable.subribe is not awaited thus (in your case) result is returned before it is assigned.

your logic is needed to be something like tihs

```
return this.observable1().pipe(mergeMap((param1) => {
  return this.observable2().pipe(map((param1) => {
    return <logged_in_Result>;
  }));
}));
```